# Overnight Rules Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data:

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzlaF.png)

| StartDate | StartTime | EndDate | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/10/2020 | 09:00:00 | 12/13/2020 | 12:00:00 |

And I want an output as follows:

[Output Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhv6O.png)

| StartDate | StartTime | EndDate | EndTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/10/2020 | 09:00:00 | 12/10/2020 | 23:59:59 | 14:59:59 |
| 12/11/2020 | 00:00:00 | 12/11/2020 | 23:59:59 | 23:59:59 |
| 12/12/2020 | 00:00:00 | 12/12/2020 | 23:59:59 | 23:59:59 |
| 12/13/2020 | 00:00:00 | 12/13/2020 | 12:00:00 | 12:00:00 |

How is it possible in T-SQL? I am running SQL Server 14.x version.

My attempt:

```
 With cte as(

            Select [Start Date] StartDate ,
            Case
                When [Start Date] = [End Date] Then Duration
                When [Start Date] != [End Date] Then  DateDiff(MINUTE,[Start Time],'23:59:59')
            End
                as ShutdownTime
                 from [dbo].[Delay]
                 where 
                    [Start Date]>=@StartDate and [Start Date]<= @EndDate                        
        Union 

            Select [End Date] StartDate, 
             DateDiff(Minute,'00:00:00', [End Time])
            as ShutdownTime
                 from [dbo].[Delay]
                 where  [Start Date] !=[End Date]
                 and
                    [Start Date]>=@StartDate and [Start Date]<= @EndDate                    
                    
                    
        )
    Select StartDate, Sum(ShutDownTime/cast(60 as float)) ShutDownTime
    from cte group by StartDate
```

If it is less than 24 hrs. it works fine. but in case of more than 24 hrs, it fails.

Comment: If you had read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), then you could have created a better (looking) question.  Now you only have to privide some info on your attempts and explain where you are stuk (like Dale asked)

Comment: I have provided my try and the reason why it is failing

Comment: Please explain the duration calculation.

Comment: oops, I did make an error in overtyping the picture to text.... This is leading to some questions about duration....   I will correct this now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is much simpler to work with date/times rather than having them in separate columns.

Second, you want a recursive CTE.  Here is working code:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(datetime, startdate) + convert(datetime, starttime) as day_startdt,
             (case when t.startdate = t.enddate 
                   then v.enddt else dateadd(day, 1, t.startdate)
              end) as day_enddt,
             v.enddt, 1 as lev
      from t cross apply
           (values (convert(datetime, enddate) + convert(datetime, endtime))) v(enddt)
      union all
      select cte.day_enddt,
             (case when cte.day_enddt < convert(date, cte.enddt)
                   then dateadd(day, 1, cte.day_enddt) else cte.enddt 
              end) as day_enddt,
             cte.enddt, lev + 1
      from cte
      where cte.day_startdt < dateadd(day, -1, cte.enddt)
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee483a44de983ca532a6e1eb10231948) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this includes full days, which makes sense to me.  It does not calculate the duration, because that calculation does not look correct in the question -- and if it is, you need to explain it.

You can easily split this into separate `date`/`time` columns if you want, although I don't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a View with calculated column:

```
CREATE VIEW [schema_name.]view_name 
AS SELECT
    StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime, 
    DATEDIFF(hour, StartTime, EndTime) + ':' +
    DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, EndTime) + ':' +
    DATEDIFF(second, StartTime, EndTime) + ':' AS 'Duration'
FROM [schema_name.]table_name;
```

**Links:**

- [CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

If your date/time isn't of type DATETIME (or similar), have a look at [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-10-12';
DECLARE @StartTime TIME = '09:00:00';
DECLARE @EndDate   DATE = '2020-12-12';
DECLARE @EndTime   TIME = '12:00:00';

WITH cte as (
  select 
    @StartDate as StartDate,
    @StartTime as StartTime,
    CASE WHEN @StartDate<>@EndDate THEN @StartDate ELSE @EndDate END as EndDate,
    CASE WHEN @StartDate<>@EndDate THEN CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME) ELSE @EndTime END as EndTime
  union all
  select 
    DATEADD(day,1,StartDate),
    StartTime,
    DATEADD(day,1,EndDate),
    CASE WHEN EndDate<>@EndDate THEN CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME) ELSE @EndTime END as EndTime
  from cte
  where EndDate <= @EndDate
  )
  select 
     StartDate,
     StartTime,
     EndDate,
     EndTime,
     CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second,StartTime,EndTime),0)) as Duration
  from cte;
```

The duration is calculated as the difference between `StartTime` and `EndTime`, because storing values in a database that depend only on other fields (in the same table) is not a smart thing to do.